# How do I implelment Android 6.0 Runtime Permissions On Existing App

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

## Problem:

I have an existing app that I would like to implement Android 6.0's Runtime Permissions on. I have read a lot of different things on Runtime Permissions, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around all the different snippets. Nothing I have found actually shows how to implement this into an existing Activity.

## Other Points

When I run my existing application targeting SDK v23 I get the permission error as expected, but the permission error I get is not even a permission that I am requesting. I have the SEND_SMS permission in the Manifest file, but the error I am getting is for READ_SMS. My app runs fine on pre 6.0 without READ_SMS.

I would like the my app to ask for permission as soon as the app is launched because the sole purpose of the app is the send an SMS message, so without that permission there is no other use for the app.

## Questions:

How would I implement Runtime Permissions for SEND_SMS into my existing Activity as soon as the app is launched?

Does the handling of these permission need to run in a background thread?

Do I also need permissions for READ_SMS since that is the permission error that it is giving (even though that permission has never been used on my app)?

### My Existing Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
AutoCompleteTextView txtContract;
EditText txtTrip;
EditText txtDate;
Button btnSend;
Button btnUpdate;
String today;

String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

private static final String API_KEY = "abcxyz";
private static final String CONTRACT_REGEX = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){5}$";
private static final String TRIP_REGEX = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,10}$";
private static final String DATE_REGEX = "^\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}$";
private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "1234567890";
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";

private BroadcastReceiver sendBroadcastReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReceiver;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // TODO - IMPLEMENT RUNTIME PERMISSIONS FOR ANDROID >= 6.0

    try {



        // Initialize Views
        txtContract = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContract);
        txtTrip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTrip);
        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);


        // Set Listeners
        txtDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);


        // Set Date To Today And Format
        final Calendar td = Calendar.getInstance();
        int tYear = td.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int tMonth = td.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int tDay = td.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        td.set(tYear, tMonth, tDay);
        today = sdf.format(td.getTime());

        txtDate.setText(today);


        // Check If Device Is Capable Of Sending SMS
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) &&
                !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        // Send Receiver
        sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Requesting trip...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };


        // Delivery Receiver
        deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trip request successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Trip request failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };


        // Register Receivers
        registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));


        // Set Up Adapter For Autocomplete
        initializeAutoCompleteAdapter();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in MainActivity.onCreate: " + ex.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}


// Auto Complete Adapter
public void initializeAutoCompleteAdapter() {

    // Set Database Handler
    final DBHelper DBHelper = new DBHelper(getBaseContext());

    // Set Up Adapter For Autocomplete (This does not run on the main UI thread)
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { "contract" },
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
            0);

    txtContract.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {

            final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("contract");
            return cursor.getString(colIndex);

        }
    });

    mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence description) {

            String strContract = txtContract.getText().toString();
            return DBHelper.getContract(strContract);

        }
    });

}


// OnClickListener Handler
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Handle Clicked View
    switch (v.getId()) {

        // Date Field
        case R.id.txtDate:

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0);
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            // Set Up DatePicker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                            // Define A New Calendar For Formatting
                            final Calendar cf = Calendar.getInstance();

                            // Format Selected Date
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
                            cf.set(year,month,day);
                            String selectedDate = sdf.format(cf.getTime());

                            // Add Selected Date To EditText Field
                            txtDate.setText(selectedDate);
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);


            // Set Max Date
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
            c.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());


            // Set Min Date
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-5);
            c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());


            // Display DatePicker
            datePickerDialog.show();

        break;

        // Submit Button
        case R.id.btnSend:

            Boolean rval = true;

            if (!Validation.isValid(txtContract, CONTRACT_REGEX, "Invalid Contract #", true)) rval = false;
            if (!Validation.isValid(txtTrip, TRIP_REGEX, "Invalid Trip #", true)) rval = false;
            if (!Validation.isValid(txtDate, DATE_REGEX, "Invalid Date", true)) rval = false;

            if(rval) {
                new ValidateAndSend(this).execute();
            }

        break;


        // Update Contract DB
        case R.id.btnUpdate:

            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            new POSTAsync(this).execute(API_KEY, mPhoneNumber);

        break;

    }
}

// Validate And Send
class ValidateAndSend extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>{

    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> MainActivityWeakRef;

    public ValidateAndSend(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        super();
        this.MainActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);
    }

    // Define Variables
    String strContract = txtContract.getText().toString();
    String strTrip = txtTrip.getText().toString();
    String strDate = txtDate.getText().toString();
    String strMessage = strContract.concat("|").concat(strTrip).concat("|").concat(strDate);
    Boolean rval = true;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... contract) {

        DBHelper DBHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        if (DBHelper.validateContract(strContract) < 1) rval = false;

        return rval;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean rval){

        if(rval){
            // Hide Keyboard
            View view = MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus();
            if(view != null){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            if (MainActivityWeakRef.get() != null && !MainActivityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
                // Confirm Details
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Confirm Trip");
                alert.setMessage("CONTRACT: " + strContract + "\nTRIP: " + strTrip + "\nDATE: " + strDate);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        // Send SMS
                        sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER, strMessage);

                        // Clear Fields
                        txtContract.setText("");
                        txtTrip.setText("");
                        txtDate.setText(today);
                    }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Cancelled
                    }
                });

                // Show Alert
                alert.show();
            }
        }
        else{
            txtContract.setError("Invalid contract #");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You may need to update contracts.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}


// Send SMS
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

}
```

}

Comment: see my answer , will help you understand.

Comment: You'll want to check the permission each time you try to send an SMS (regardless of whether they gave you permission at app open or not).  The whole deal with runtime permissions is that the user can revoke them at any time and your app should be able to handle it - so lets say they give you permission at app open, then the background the app, revoke the permission, go back into the app and try to send - if you don't check again, you are going to crash when you try to send the SMS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime permission model for Android 6.0 is mainly divided into part

**1. Checking Permission**

**2. Requesting Permission**

you can create two method for this thing in your activity, As follow

**Check Permission**

```
private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}
```

**Request Permission**

```
private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)){

        Toast.makeText(context,"Read Sms Allowed.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Last but not least you need to override the **onRequestPermissionsResult** method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access SMS.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Denied, You cannot access SMS.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

as you asked **do i need to run this in thread .. answer is No** Just do this in main thread

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do less code then, please use [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) is an Android library that simplifies the process of requesting permissions at runtime.