# Marshmallow Permission Error

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I Am Working On Music Player Application So I have to get All Songs From Memory Card And I successfully got songs from Memory Card Application and Working Fine On Lollipop.

**Problem**
Marshmallow Run Time Permission I also Add Run time Permission For Marshmallow but App Still Crashing..

Here Is My Full Code Please Tell Me Where I have To write Run Time Permission For Marshmallow.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;
    ListView musiclist;
    Cursor musiccursor;
    int music_column_index;
    int count;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init_phone_music_grid();
        if(isReadStorageAllowed()){
            //If permission is already having then showing the toast
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You already have the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Existing the method with return
            return;
        }

        //If the app has not the permission then asking for the permission
        requestStoragePermission();
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
            //Here you can explain why you need this permission
            //Explain here why you need this permission
        }

        //And finally ask for the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    //This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        //Checking the request code of our request
        if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

            //If permission is granted
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                //Displaying a toast
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted now you can read the storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
                Toast.makeText(this,"Oops you just denied the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }



    private boolean isReadStorageAllowed() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            return true;


        return false;

    }


    private void init_phone_music_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };

        musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
        count = musiccursor.getCount();
        musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
        musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            System.gc();
            music_column_index = musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

            try {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

    };



    public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            System.gc();
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                music_column_index = musiccursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                music_column_index = musiccursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                tv.setText(id);
            } else
         tv.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(R.color.colorAccent)));
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            return tv;
        }
    }}
```

Please Don't Mark Duplicate Just Correct my Permission
Thanks

**Crash Report**:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.j.musicapp, PID: 28606
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.j.musicapp/com.example.j.musicapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=28606, uid=10161 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=28606, uid=10161 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1621)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:445)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:2227)
                                                                            at com.example.j.musicapp.MainActivity.init_phone_music_grid(MainActivity.java:100)
                                                                            at com.example.j.musicapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: post the logcat details

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34959331/4919210  check this answer !!

Comment: Ok Sir Wait............

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Please Take a glance on my crash report

Comment: `requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Check how did u import your _Manifest_ ? It should be _android.Manifest_ not your app manifest.

Comment: Sir please see my code i added permison in OnCreate and Manifiest too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow/41221852#41221852 Check this it's work on API level 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the sample code for marshmallow and above versions:

```
  public static class Utility {
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
            int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                        alert.show();

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is a method that checks for permission for reading external storage. please refer the code and manipulate accordingly.
Hope this helps you out.

also add this code in onCreate method

```
 boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: But if user denied the permission then??

Comment: if once user denied then it will again ask for it as in my else condition i have called it again. if you do not want to make it mandatory then you can remove the else code

Comment: yup got it thnx again

Comment: alreday did bro

Comment: buddy you have given a tick and votes are still zero.once you will click the up vote arrow it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this generic code structure see if matches... I practically followed it, worked well

```
if(permissionNotGranted){
       requestPermission() ;
}else{
   //Permission granted, good to go!
    doWhateverWithPermission() ; 
}
```

You are good with `onRequestPermissionsResult` .. just see the structure. Hope it helps!