# FileOutputStream always triggers the ioexception

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android app and it's my first time using Java. I'm trying to export a bitmap as a PNG file and save it to the directory. However, the `FileOutPutStream` always triggers the `ioexception`. I've checked the path by using `isDirectory` and it returns true. Could someone please look at my code to see where I get wrong?

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
        TextView result = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            return;
        }
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //get image Uri
                Uri imageUri = resultIntent.getData();
                //get image path through Uri
                Bitmap bitmap;
                //getting path of external DCIM directory
                File dstPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                //checking if directory exists
                if(dstPath.isDirectory()) {
                    result.setText("True");

                }
                String filename = "test.png";
                File file = new File(dstPath,filename);
                //result.setText(file.toString());

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    //result.setText(bitmap.toString());
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    result.setText("flag");
                    if(bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)==false){
                        result.setText("0");
                    }
                    else {
                        result.setText("1");
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                } catch(IOException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    result.setText("false");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace

```java
2020-02-26 12:55:23.534 10261-10261/com.example.webviewproject E/YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG: I got an error
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/test.png (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180)
        at com.example.webviewproject.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:102)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace also

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've just added the stack trace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/downloadedfilem.jpg (Permission denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688354/java-io-filenotfoundexception-storage-emulated-0-downloadedfilem-jpg-permissi)

Comment: Note that even with those permissions, this code will not work by default on Android 10 or higher: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57116335/115145

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to give run time permissions to access the file

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688354/java-io-filenotfoundexception-storage-emulated-0-downloadedfilem-jpg-permissi/47688482)

Comment: That works, thank you so much!!!